# Как загрузить определенную строку из текстового файла в переменную?

Tags: get, php, строки

Номер находится в `get` запросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Положить каждую строку в отдельный элемент массива(функция **file()**). Затем получить из GET запроса нужный номер строки. Затем обратиться к тому элементу массива номер которого Вы получили из GET запроса - 1.

```
$str_array = file('path/to/file');
print $str_array[$_GET['line_num']-1];
```

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, код

Comment: @cas-live, почему Вы задаете вопрос здесь и ждете халявы вместо того чтобы самому почитать об этом и разобраться. Саморазвитие это хорошо.

Comment: Да это я понимаю но вот где я бы почитал